How to implement the exposure adjustment like Adobe Lightroom using OpenCV?
I try to create a image editor features like what are provided by Adobe Lightroom with Python and OpenCV. One of them is Exposure Adjustment on the image. The issue I always have is after increase the exposure, it caused the adjusted image has yellowish or orangish tint. I look up what is the cause of this yellowish / orangish tint. It because the non-uniform adjustment of the RGB channels. May I know what is the real caused and how I can solve this issue?
So, to adjust exposure I have tried several approach. I am expecting to adjust the image exposure of the input as close as possible to adjustment with adobe lightroom.
This is the image I am using as input and the expected image result from adobe lightroom with 3.67 exposure value:



Using gamma correction, because I read the case of RAW image taken from camera usually will be adjusted when display to monitor. I think one of the root cause is because our human eyes not perceived the light in linear way. And this is the result of gamma adjustment with this code implementation.

def adjust_gamma_original(image, gamma=1.0):
    inv_gamma = 1.0 / gamma
    table = np.array([((i / 255.0) ** inv_gamma) * 255 for i in np.arange(0, 256)]).astype("uint8")
    adjusted_image = cv2.LUT(image, table)
    return adjusted_image

This is the result of gamma correction

I am trying to increase the exposure by applying power of 2 to every pixel. But even though the light brightness is increase, it causes yellowish/orange-ish tint show up the the faces. Which is not ideal because the exposure increment in adobe lightroom didn't cause this issue.

def apply_exposure_compensation(image, exposure_factor):
    """
    Apply exposure compensation to an image.
    
    :param image: Input image.
    :param exposure_factor: Factor to adjust exposure. Positive values increase exposure, negative values decrease exposure.
    :return: Image with adjusted exposure.
    """
    # Convert the image to float for precision
    image_float = img_as_float(image)
    
    # Adjust exposure by multiplying the image with the exposure factor
    adjusted_image = image_float * (2 ** exposure_factor)
    
    # Clip values to stay within valid range [0, 1] and convert back to uint8
    adjusted_image = np.clip(adjusted_image, 0, 1)
    adjusted_image = img_as_ubyte(adjusted_image)
    return adjusted_image

Output result exposure power of 2

I try to using HSV to because I read if I only want to focus on the brightness without affecting the color tint, then I can adjust the V in HSV. But after I increase it, it makes the output result become further to what I want like adobe lightroom.

def apply_exposure_compensation_hsv(image, exposure_factor):
    """
    Apply exposure compensation to an image by adjusting the brightness in the HSV color space.
    
    :param image: Input image.
    :param exposure_factor: Factor to adjust exposure. Positive values increase exposure, negative values decrease exposure.
    :return: Image with adjusted exposure.
    """
    # Convert the image to HSV color space
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV).astype(np.float32)
    
    # Adjust the V (brightness) channel
    h, s, v = cv2.split(hsv)
    v = v * (2 ** exposure_factor)
    v = np.clip(v, 0, 255)
    
    # Merge the channels back
    hsv_adjusted = cv2.merge([h, s, v]).astype(np.uint8)
    
    # Convert back to BGR color space
    adjusted_image = cv2.cvtColor(hsv_adjusted, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
    return adjusted_image

Exposure increment power of 2 on HSV color channel

yeah all of that isn't gonna work. you need to first remove the gamma mapping. then you've got linear values. then you can scale them. finally you can reapply the gamma... but before that, you might need some simple tone mapping (a HDR thing) to make sure your pixel values don't clip hard, or weirdly. by that I mean map bright pixels such that they desaturate as they approach clipping.

Hi @ChristophRackwitz,
Thanks for the suggestion. I am kinda new in this image processing stuff.   for remove the gamma mapping, does it mean I need to do the gamma correction first? Like convert every pixel to the linear values with the inverse gamma?
For simple tone mapping, do we have any standard for doing that? Does it mean I need to do it before clipping process?
